# What is this movie about creatures from pictures trying to burn a house down?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched a movie years ago about a family who just moved into a house. They had two little girls and they had their own room (I believe it was a play house type room) and they drew pictures of these creatures and their parents were concerned.

I remember at the end the creatures tried to burn down the home. Please help me find this movie!

Movie was in English. I know it was between 2000, but before 2013. The girls were approximately 5 and 6. Never really showed the creatures. They always showed up black.

Comment: Can you provide more details. What language was the film, what was the approximate year, what age roughly were the girls, where was the film set, were there any quotes/phrases in the movie you remember and what did the creatures look like?

Comment: Movie was in English. I know it was between 2000, but before 2013. The girls were approximately 5 and 6. Never really showed the creatures. They always showed up black. I cant remember much more, thats why im having such a hard time finding it.

Comment: But I defiantly remember them drawing pictures in there playhouse and i remember the creatures tried burning down the house at the end. I think they did burn down the house, not quite sure though.

Comment: Sounds like a few versions of the Amityville Horror series.

Comment: @JohnP: That was my thought, although the ending doesn't sound familiar.

Comment: @AndrewMartin - Amityville Dollhouse has a burning ending, and one of the others does too IIRC. It's a long shot, but until we get more details... <shrug>

Comment: @JohnP: Didn't realise that. There's so many Amityville films!

Comment: Wow this sounds both familiar and very intriguing.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to take a shot here because it sounds very similar to [Don't Be Afraid of the Dark (2010)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1270761/?ref_=nv_sr_1) in which a little girl and the family battle black creatures from the basement, the "Tooth Fairies".

In flashbacks of previous families there were other children, multiple children which is what you may be recalling.

> At Blackwood Manor in Providence County, Rhode Island, renowned
> wildlife painter Lord Blackwood summons his housekeeper into the
> basement where he reluctantly kills her with a hammer and chisel. He
> removes her teeth, as well as his own, and offers them to mysterious
> creatures down an ash pit within an old fireplace; however, the
> creatures demand the teeth of children. Blackwood begs for them to
> give back his kidnapped son, only to be dragged down the ash pit by
> the creatures. In the present day, 8-year old Sally Hurst arrives in
> Rhode Island to live with her father Alex and his girlfriend Kim, both
> restoring Blackwood Manor to put it on the market for their client Mr.
> Jacoby. Sally is depressed due to her mother forcefully putting her in
> Alex's care and giving her copious amounts of Adderall. On the first
> night of her stay, the melodious tune from a carousel-styled
> nightlight awakens the creatures in the ash pit. The next day, Sally
> wanders the grounds and finds the hidden basement's skylight. One of
> the workmen restoring the house, Mr. Harris, warns her, Alex and Kim
> not to venture into the basement, although they do regardless. Sally
> takes interest in the sealed fireplace where she hears the creatures
> calling her name and follows the mysterious voices. "BE AFRAID" is
> written in runes above it.
>
> Sally opens the fireplace to meet the
> creatures and finds one of the old housekeeper's teeth. The creatures
> quickly prove to be hostile, stealing Alex's razor and shredding Kim's
> clothes. Alex immediately blames Sally and finds a 19th-century silver
> coin in her possession, which she found under her pillow after the
> tooth disappeared. Alex and Kim head into town on a business trip and
> Sally sneaks to the basement to talk with the creatures, but Harris
> sends her away and tries to seal the fireplace. The creatures emerge
> and brutally wound him with his own tools and he is hospitalized.
> Sally's increasingly frightening encounters with the creatures prompt
> Alex to call a therapist to talk to Sally, who draws a sketch of one
> of the creatures that attacked her under her bedsheets.
>
> Kim visits
> Harris in the hospital, who tells her to find the unpublished artwork
> of Lord Blackwood in the local library. The librarian reveals the
> artwork, one of which is of a creature whom he describes as being like
> tooth fairies, which every now and again turns a human into one of
> their own. Kim races home as Sally is attacked again by the creatures
> while having a bath, the lead creature being a transformed Lord
> Blackwood who proclaims the creatures will make Sally one of their
> own. Kim finds an undiscovered mural painted by Lord Blackwood in the
> basement, depicting his son being transformed by the creatures. Kim
> confronts Alex who is more interested in hosting a dinner for Mr.
> Jacoby and friends. However, he finally realizes what is happening
> when Sally is trapped in the library by the creatures, but she fends
> them off by using her camera flash to distract them.
>
> Alex and Kim
> decide to flee the house with Sally, but both are ambushed by the
> creatures and knocked out, Sally tries to wake Kim up but also gets
> ambushed by the creatures and is knocked unconscious. When Sally wakes
> up, her feet have been tied up with rope, and the creatures are
> starting to drag her to the basement for her transformation. Kim
> awakens and goes to basement confronting the creatures, cutting the
> rope around Sally's feet but only to get herself in the ropes and her
> leg broken by it as she struggles to get free. The creatures drag Kim
> into the fireplace, as a distraught Sally crushes the creature who
> used to be Lord Blackwood to death with a large flashlight. Alex
> arrives just as Kim disappears, and the father and daughter mourn
> their loss.
>
> Some time later, both return to the abandoned mansion to
> leave a drawing of Kim there, but a gust of wind blows the drawing
> into the creatures' lair, where the transformed Kim is heard
> convincing the creatures to stay where they are and just go deeper
> into the basement – for they will forget in time, and others will come
> – claiming they have "all the time in the world".

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Be_Afraid_of_the_Dark_%282011_film%29)

Answer (score 2):

Found it! I was just trying to remember the name of this movie. I came across this so I figured I'd help you out.

The movie is called [Inhabited](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0329224/?ref_=kw_li_tt) (2003):

> A family [with 2 kids] discovers a race of ancient creatures are living under their home.

The house burns down in the end. [Here's the trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WV-CFkRJCtc).

Answer (score 0):

I am confident that the movie you remember is "Don't Be Afraid of the
Dark." This was a made-for-TV movie that aired on ABC in 1973. Scared
the willies out of lots of people, including me.

In the movie, a young couple move into an old house. There are little
humanoid gnomelike creatures living in the walls and basement. They
call to her in whispery voices through the fireplace and air grates.
The woman's name is Sally, and the little people call out "Saaaalllly,
we want yooooou" and similar things, causing Sally (and her husband)
to think she is losing her mind.

You'll find an excellent synopsis of the plot here, complete with photos:

Terror Trap: Don't Be Afraid of the Dark 
http://www.terrortrap.com/television/dontbeafraidofthedark/

Answer (score 0):

ITS INHABITED! I remember because I've been trying to look for this movie for years and people kept telling me in was "don't be afraid of the dark" but it's not.

Comment: You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.